# Is there a way to utilize Shift key + Mouse Wheelcroll to sideways scroll in flutter ScrollView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-scrollbar

In my flutter app, I have a section that can scroll both vertically and horizontally. What I am wanting to do is hold the `Shift Key` and scroll with my mouse wheel to enable horizontal scrolling without clicking the horizontal scroll bar (a normal shortcut on many websites that would be nice to implement in this web version of the app). Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a feature that was filed in Flutter. Currently, the ticket was still open and was being handled by engineers. See [this GitHub feature request](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/3123).

Also, the feature is related to [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75180). You can keep track on that features.

Comment: This is actually helpful. I haven't been able to find any info on the issue and I'll go read up on those links.